# Angular 2 importing another "sibling" module injects the wrong Component

Tags: angular, typescript, components, angular2-routing, ng-modules

So I have a module structure like this:

```
app 
----pages
---------dashboard
---------posts
```

Both `dashboard` and `posts` have their own routing.

Here is how the routing looks like:

**Pages**

```
const routes: Routes = [ 
  {
    path: '',
    component: Pages,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './dashboard#DashboardModule' } 
      { path: 'posts', loadChildren: './posts#PostsModule' }
    ]
  }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

**Dashboard**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent
  }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

**Posts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: PostsComponent
    },
    ...
];
const routing = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

**Everything works fine but when I try to import the `PostsModule` in the `DashboardModule` like this:**

```
import { PostsModule } from '../posts';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    routing, // Dashboard routes
    CommonModule, 
    ...
    PostsModule
  ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

and load `http://localhost:3000/#/dashboard`, it shows the `PostsComponent`, instead of `DashboardComponent` just because I imported the "sibling" module

**How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that by loading the `PostsModule` into the `DashboardModule`, you are also importing the `PostModule` routes, which is incorrect. Because the order of the route definitions matters, the incorrect component is placed in the page

Without seeing the full modules, it's impossible to say your intended design. However, I'd separate any common services and components from the `PostsModule` into a `PostsCommonModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     //common components
  ],
  providers; [
     //common service
  ]
})
export class PostsCommonModule { }
```

with can then be imported by both `PostsModule` and `DashboardModule`:

```
import { PostsCommonModule  } from './posts-common.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [PostsCommonModule]
  //...
})
export class PostsModule { }

//dashboard.module

import { PostsCommonModule  } from '../posts/posts-common.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [PostsCommonModule]
  //...
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```